# Minimum element in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm solving exercise 2 from [lecture 3 of Berkeley's CS 61A (2012)](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/disc/disc3.pdf):

> Write a function `min_element` that returns the minimum element in a tuple.
>
> ```
> def min_element(tup):
>     """ Returns the minimum element in tup.
>     >>> a = (1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
>     >>> min_element(a)
>     1
>     """
> ```

I know that Python has a built-in `min` function, but at this point in the course, the only operations on tuples that we have studied are indexing `[1]` `[-1]`, slicing `[1:]`, and concatenation `+`, so my solution needs to restrict itself accordingly.

My solution:

```
def min_element(tup):
    """ Returns the minimum element in tup.
    >>> a = (1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
    >>> min_element(a)
    1
    """
    def find_min(tup, min):
        if not tup:
           return min
        else:
           min = tup[0] if tup[0] < min else min
           return min_element(tup[1:], min)
    if tup:
        return find_min(tup[1:], tup[0])
```

Can this solution be improved?

Comment: Is `min(tup)` allowed?

Comment: you mean python provided `min` function? No.

Comment: One supplementary, this [doc](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/disc/disc3.pdf) says: "A sequence has an element corresponding to any `non-negative integer` index less than its length, starting at 0 for the first element.". But python allows `tup[:-1]`?

Comment: Negative indexes just count backwards from the end, and can therefore be disregarded. `tup[:-1]` is shorthand for `tup[:len(tup)-1]`.

Comment: @overexchange: I've rewritten the question so that it clearly explains *why* you have these constraints on your solution, where they come from, and that you know about the built-in `min` function. We can't read your mind, so you need to tell us these things in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the recursive version of your code by dropping elements until you are left with just one, and then comparing pairs sequential pairs:

```
def min_element_recur(tup):
    if len(tup) == 1:
        return tup[0]
    elif len(tup) >= 2:
        a = tup[0]
        b = min_element_recur(tup[1:])
        return a if a<b else b
```

If you have learned `reduce` and `lambda` expressions, you can implement the operation by reducing on the minimum of two elements (if you are using python 3, you need `from functools import reduce`).  This is basically the same as Danny's approach.

```
def min_element_reduce(tup):
   return reduce(lambda x, y: x if x<y else y, (1,2,3,4,-1,5))
```

Finally, this is a bit too simple so it may not be allowed, but you can take the first elements of the sorted version of the tuple:

```
def min_element_sorted(tup):
   return sorted(tup)[0]
```

Danny's solution is probably the most straightforward, though.

Comment: It is straightforward, but I prefer this solution ): Can we categorise such recursive style?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "categorize".

Answer (score 3):

Berkeley CS61A alum here. Your solution looks fine. Having sat through many a lecture where the prof would go through problems like this, I can pretty much guarantee this is the solution that would have been given:

```
def min_element(tup):
    min = tup[0]
    for element in tup[1:]:
        if element < min:
            min = element
    return min
```

So this solution might be considered by someone really pedantic to be a bit "better" than yours since it is less verbose and because, in general, recursion tends to be slower than iteration. Your solution works just fine though :)

Answer (score 2):

If I pass the empty tuple to your function, what happens? The condition `if tup:` fails, so control reaches the end of the function. As it happens, reaching the end of a function is equivalent to `return None`, but it's a bad idea to rely on this (because it's not clear to the reader what happens in this case; also, it's [deprecated in the Python style guide (PEP8)](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-April/139054.html)).

The result is the same as if the function succeeds and found that `None` is the minimum element of the tuple, as if you'd called `min_element((None,))`, so it could potentially lead to errors elsewhere in a program.

It would be better to raise an exception in this case. The built-in [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) raises `ValueError`:

```
>>> min(())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```